# Draggable column using React MUI X DataGrid

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid, mui-x

I am using **DataGrid** from React MUI X (Material UI). I am trying for draggable column in this DataGrid. Draggable columns are available in **DataGridPro**, but it is not allowed to use **DataGridPro** for me. Any suggestions how can we write custom code for draggable columns.

Comment: You can achieve this by using `rowReordering` prop of `DataGrid`. Check this official example here https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-ordering/

Comment: I think he meant draggable column and not `row`

Comment: @SimranSingh I am trying for columns and no provision is there in DataGrid for column reordering